# Inkscape: Importing SVG file produces unusably huge object in document

Tags: resolution, inkscape, size

So the ultimate goal here is to produce a 600dpi vector file for use with a digital printer.
I've gone to great lengths to insure that all the original images (png) are 600 dpi. These average 5-8 inches printed, so 3000px by 4000px for the most part. I then used Adobe's online "convert-to-svg", and it "seems" to be correct, at least they're all generally fine visually and the dimensions are reasonable.

Now comes the Inkscape challenge.   I created a new document that is **12x14 inches**. And intend to import each of the SVG files to the Inkscape document.

However, while doing this, the dialog asks for a "DPI to be used rendered SVG".  If I specify 600 (as required by the printer), then it imports the source SVG, but it's about ***1,192"*** wide!! according to the measuring tool (roughly 6x the original width)

I'm going to assume this is operator error, but what "the heck" am I doing wrong?  I certain don't need a 1200 inch object, but the 8" 600dpi source SVG vector file is what I want in the Inkscape file.  I would expect that an object from an 8" file would be about 2/3 across the document, but it dwarfs the 12x14" document!

Please help!  And thank you in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

My trials using your pixels parameters rendered svg files, but when opening the svg's into Illustrator the original picture is sitting on a page with a mass of white space at top and bottom. The landscape formatted image as an SVG conversion was 90mm wide by 1172mm high (should have been approx 55mm). Perhaps YOUR massive conversion image also has a large amount of redundant white space added to it in the conversion process.

Comment: It may well be, though it didn't seem to be, changing the Import DPI had an affect, but didn't know how that would affect the final file for the printer, so I abandoned using Adobe for the vectors, and did each manually with Inkscape - worked beautifully.